# How can I create a dll that can be used for both c++ and c#?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, win-universal-app, portable-class-library

I need to develop a library that can be used for both c++ application and also by c# universal store app.
My research so far:

- Developing in c++ wont help because c# uwp will only accept PCL.
- Developing as PCL in c# cannot be added to c++ applications.

(I am not sure about the second case. Correct me if I am wrong.)
Is there way to developing a common library ? or I have to develop it in those two platforms separately.

Comment: How about developing a native library, and also a PCL that uses that library (to use in UWP)?

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz I will give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a C++ library, you can use it from C++ (obviously) and you can create a C++/CX wrapper for this C++ library that can be used from C#.

Comment: I did that. But when I was trying to add the reference I was getting "the project targets .netcore while the file reference targets .net framework" error.

Comment: So you probably created the wrapper with a wrong target, you have to change it (Windows Runtime Component (Universal Windows)).

Comment: my code will get build with /clr. I cannot do the same with WinRT. my entire code is c++/cli. Is that still possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use COM objects. You can then import the library in Visual Studio and then they will be available as regular objects.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973800.aspx

From the CPP point of view to create COM objects the "atl" is probably the best approach.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/727z646z.aspx

COM objects can be hard to implement but they can be imported in many languages and compilers.